# Performance Improvement: Replacing recursive method call by a recursive sql query

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, query-optimization, recursive-query

I have started on a new job and my first task is to improve performance of code for which user action takes 40 mins currently sometimes. On analysis I found that there is a Parent - Child - Grandchilren - ....and so on tree kind of relationship and a recursive method is implemented in current code which is taking time, because network calls to database are being made recursively.

As an improvement, I want to hit database once and fetch all data recursively at once.

Service layer code (this method calls itself recursively):

```
private void **processRecommendedEvaluationMetaForReadyToExport**(EvaluationMeta parentEvaluationMeta,
                                                                  Set<EvaluationMeta> childEvaluationMetas,
                                                                  Map<String, MCGEvaluationMetadata> mcgHsimContentVersionEvaluationMetadataMap) {

        // get the list of child evaluation recommendations for the given parent evaluation
        Map<String, List<MCGEvaluationMetaMaster>> hsimAndchildEvaluationDefinitionsMap = mcgEvaluationMetaDao.findRecommendedChildEvaluationMeta(parentEvaluationMeta.getId());

        Iterator childEvaluationDefinitionsMapIterator = hsimAndchildEvaluationDefinitionsMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (childEvaluationDefinitionsMapIterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry childEvaluationDefinition = (Map.Entry) childEvaluationDefinitionsMapIterator.next();

            if (childEvaluationDefinition.getValue() != null && !((List<MCGEvaluationMetaMaster>) childEvaluationDefinition.getValue()).isEmpty()) {
                for (MCGEvaluationMetaMaster mcgEvaluationMetaMaster : (List<MCGEvaluationMetaMaster>) childEvaluationDefinition.getValue()) {                  

                    MCGEvaluationMetadata mcgEvaluationMetadata = mcgHsimContentVersionEvaluationMetadataMap.get(mcgEvaluationMetaMaster.getHsim() + mcgEvaluationMetaMaster.getMcgContentVersion().getContentVersion());
                    // consider only evaluation definitions which are either published/disabled status to be marked as ready to export and also skip adding the
                    // parent evaluation meta as it will be marked as ready to export later
                    
                    if (canMcgEvaluationBeMarkedAsReadyToExport(mcgEvaluationMetadata) && !childEvaluationMetas.contains(mcgEvaluationMetadata.getEvaluationMeta()) &&
                            !parentEvaluationMeta.getResource().getName().equals(mcgEvaluationMetadata.getEvaluationMeta().getResource().getName())) {

                        childEvaluationMetas.add(mcgEvaluationMetadata.getEvaluationMeta());
                        **processRecommendedEvaluationMetaForReadyToExport**(mcgEvaluationMetadata.getEvaluationMeta(), childEvaluationMetas, mcgHsimContentVersionEvaluationMetadataMap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

DAO Layer:

```
private static final String GET_RECOMMENDED_CHILD_EVALUATIONS =
            "MCGEvaluationMetaRecommendation.getRecommendedChildEvaluations";  



  public Map<String, List<MCGEvaluationMetaMaster>> findRecommendedChildEvaluationMeta(final String evaluationMetaId) {
            Map<String, List<MCGEvaluationMetaMaster>> recommendedChildGuidelineInfo = new HashMap<>();
            if (evaluationMetaId != null) {
                final Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(GET_RECOMMENDED_CHILD_ASSESSMENTS);
                query.setParameter(ASSESSMENT_META_ID, evaluationMetaId);
                List<MCGEvaluationMetaRecommendation> resultList = query.getResultList(); // get the MCGEvaluationMetaRecommendation
    
                // for the given parent evaluation meta id
                if (resultList != null && !resultList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (MCGEvaluationMetaRecommendation mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation : resultList) {
                        populateRecommendedChildGuidelineInfo(mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation, recommendedChildGuidelineInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
            return recommendedChildGuidelineInfo;
        }   
    
    private void  populateRecommendedChildGuidelineInfo(MCGEvaluationMetaRecommendation mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation,
                                                            Map<String, List<MCGEvaluationMetaMaster>> recommendedChildGuidelineInfo){
            if (mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation.getParentEvaluationResponseDefinition() != null) {
                List<MCGEvaluationMetaMaster> mcgEvaluationMetaMasterList;
                String evaluationResponseDefinitionId = mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation.getParentEvaluationResponseDefinition().getId();
                MCGEvaluationMetaMaster mcgEvaluationMetaMaster = mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation.getChildMCGEvaluationMetaMaster();
                if (recommendedChildGuidelineInfo.get(evaluationResponseDefinitionId) != null) {
                    mcgEvaluationMetaMasterList = recommendedChildGuidelineInfo.get(evaluationResponseDefinitionId);
                    //check if there exists a list of recommended evaluation definitions for the evaluationResponseDefinitionId
                    // if so, check if the current recommended evaluation definition is already there in the list if not add it
                    // or create a new list of recommended evaluation definitions and add to it
                    if (mcgEvaluationMetaMasterList != null && !mcgEvaluationMetaMasterList.contains(mcgEvaluationMetaMaster)) {
                        mcgEvaluationMetaMasterList.add(mcgEvaluationMetaMaster);
                    }
                } else {
                    mcgEvaluationMetaMasterList = new ArrayList<>();
                    mcgEvaluationMetaMasterList.add(mcgEvaluationMetaMaster);
                    recommendedChildGuidelineInfo.put(evaluationResponseDefinitionId, mcgEvaluationMetaMasterList);
                }
            }
        }
```

Hibernate Query:

```
<query name="MCGEvaluationMetaRecommendation.getRecommendedChildEvaluations">
        <![CDATA[
      SELECT mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation
      FROM com.casenet.domain.evaluation.mcg.MCGEvaluationMetaRecommendation mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation
      INNER JOIN mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation.parentMCGEvaluationMetadata parentMCGEvaluationMeta
      WHERE parentMCGEvaluationMeta.evaluationMeta.id = :evaluationMetaId
      AND mcgEvaluationMetaRecommendation.obsolete = 0
      AND parentMCGEvaluationMeta.obsolete = 0
    ]]>
    </query>


Simplified TABLE structure below: 

Table: *MCGEvaluationMetaRecommendation*

mcg_evaluation_meta_recommendation_id
obsolete
parent_evaluation_response_definition_id
child_mcg_evaluation_meta_master_id
parent_mcg_evaluation_metadata_id

Table: *MCGEvaluationMetadata*

mcg_evaluation_metadata_id
evaluation_meta_id
mcg_evaluation_meta_master_id
created_date
obsolete
```

Below is the query I have written trying to substitute the recursive method, but something is wrong as the query keeps excecuting and doesn't complete even after 6-7 mins

```
WITH parent_child AS (
    SELECT 
        meta.mcg_evaluation_metadata_id                 METADATA_ID,
        meta.mcg_evaluation_meta_master_id              META_MASTER_ID, 
        meta.evaluation_meta_id                         META_ID,
        meta.obsolete                                   META_OBSOLETE,
        rec.mcg_evaluation_meta_recommendation_id       REC_META_RECOMM_ID,
        rec.parent_evaluation_response_definition_id    REC_PARENT_EVALUATION_RESPONSE_DEF_ID,
        rec.child_mcg_evaluation_meta_master_id         REC_CHILD_EVALUATION_META_MASTER_ID,
        rec.parent_mcg_evaluation_metadata_id           REC_PARENT_EVALUATION_METADATA_ID,
        rec.obsolete                                    REC_OBSOLETE  
    FROM
        MCGevaluationMetaRecommendation rec,
        MCGevaluationMetadata meta
    WHERE 
        rec.parent_mcg_evaluation_metadata_id = meta.mcg_evaluation_metadata_id 
),
generation AS (
    SELECT
        METADATA_ID,
        META_MASTER_ID, 
        META_ID,
        META_OBSOLETE,
        REC_META_RECOMM_ID,
        REC_PARENT_EVALUATION_RESPONSE_DEF_ID,
        REC_CHILD_EVALUATION_META_MASTER_ID,
        REC_PARENT_EVALUATION_METADATA_ID,
        REC_OBSOLETE,
        0 AS level
    FROM
        parent_child child
        WHERE child.META_ID = 'root-id-passed-as-query-param'
        AND   child.META_OBSOLETE = 0
        AND   child. REC_OBSOLETE = 0
        
    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        child.METADATA_ID,
        child.META_MASTER_ID, 
        child.META_ID,
        child.META_OBSOLETE,
        child.REC_META_RECOMM_ID,
        child.REC_PARENT_EVALUATION_RESPONSE_DEF_ID,
        child.REC_CHILD_EVALUATION_META_MASTER_ID,
        child.REC_PARENT_EVALUATION_METADATA_ID,
        child.REC_OBSOLETE,
        level+1 AS level
    FROM
        parent_child child
        JOIN generation g
        ON g.REC_CHILD_EVALUATION_META_MASTER_ID = child.META_MASTER_ID                                                          
)
SELECT  * 
FROM generation g
JOIN parent_child parent
ON g.REC_PARENT_EVALUATION_METADATA_ID = parent.METADATA_ID
ORDER BY level DESC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Please can someone help me in identifying what is wrong about my query, or if there is some other way of improving performance in this scenario. If this query works than I will handle other logic on java side.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Doesn't look daunting. Can you add a few rows of sample data and the expected result? A simplified example could be of help.

Comment: @TheImpaler MS SQL Server

Comment: The next step on your journey is looking at actual execution plans. If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create. (This is a great feature!)  And, if that doesn't help we we need to see your actual table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier for you to simply use a #temp table and a loop.
This way you get an idea on where the time is spent, how deep the rabbit hole goes etc.. It's also less overwhelming for the query engine and in my experience it is hardly ever slower than a recursive CTE.

Pseudo code:

```
DECLARE @level int, 
        @rowcount int

SET @level = 0

PRINT Convert(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + ' - Starting up...'

SELECT level = @level,
       <fields you need>
  INTO #temp
  FROM <tables>
 WHERE <filters>
 
 SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
 
 PRINT Convert(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + ' - Loaded ' + Convert(varchar, @rowcount) + ' rows for level ' + Convert(vachar, @rowcount)
 
 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx0 ON #temp (level)
 
 -- keep adding 'new generation' of children as long as there are new 'parents'
 WHILE @rowcount > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @level = @level + 1
        
        INSERT #temp (level, <fields>)
        SELECT level = @level
          FROM <tables> tbls
          JOIN #temp parent
            ON parent.level = @level - 1
           AND parent.<x> = tbls.<x>
           AND parent.<y> = tbls.<y>
            etc..
         WHERE <filters>
         
         SELECT @rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT
    
         PRINT Convert(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + ' - Loaded ' + Convert(varchar, @rowcount) + ' rows for level ' + Convert(vachar, @rowcount)    

        UPDATE STATISTICS #temp
    END
    
-- return results
SELECT * FROM #temp
```

The `UPDATE STATISTICS` might be overkill (read: premature optimization), depends on how 'different' each level is when it comes to number of children.